# Electron App Chromium Update Notice

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, chromium

I'm building a kind of kiosk app with electron and node. This application has to run on a system without any connection to the internet. Some time ago I built a html5 / javascript application for a similar purpose that runs in an offline system on chromium portable. But after few weeks chromium comes up with an annoying notice and must be updated to get rid of this message.
Will chromium bundled with electron show the same behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not happen with Electron.

Comment: Any resource to that info?

Comment: Electron has specifically removed this sort of code from chromium. If you want automatic updates for your app it's opt in. The Electron runtime does not prompt to update as breaking changes in electron could potentially break your app. The auto update mechanism you can enable updates the runtime and your code.

Comment: This is also the expected behavior for me. Thanks for point out.